# How to scroll in a list and get all elements in Appium Java

Tags: java, appium

On a mobile application i want to get all elements of a list on the screen. There are 3 data in this list and only shown 2 without scrolling.

My code is scrolling but not getting the last element's data into my list which is an issue for me.

I'm scrolling till the text i gave is found on the screen and i want to get all the data with the date being 7/5/2023. The issue is my last element also has the 7/5/23 date. But even if i pick a text below that date the code stops and loop breaks. Since it can not go back to the beginning of the loop it can not get the last data into the list.

I've shared my code below. What can i do to fix my issue?

```
String searchText = "7/5/23";
        
List <WebElement> elementsWithText = new ArrayList<>();

while (true) {
    // Find all visible elements in the list
    List<WebElement> visibleElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@text='" + searchText + "']"));

    // Add visible elements with the desired text to the list
    elementsWithText.addAll(visibleElements);

    // Scroll to the next set of elements
    driver.findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"Jacksonville Florida, Florida\"));"));
    
    // Wait for a short while to let new elements load
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    
    // Check if there are no more new elements loaded
    if (elementsWithText.size() == visibleElements.size())
        break;
}

// Print all elements with the desired text
for (WebElement element : elementsWithText)
    System.out.println(element.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wondering how to solve this, I've written the code without a while or for loop as shown below and it worked.

```
    List <WebElement> elementsList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@text='7/5/23']"));
    
    Thread.sleep(1000);
      
    driver.findElements(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"Jacksonville Florida, Florida\"));"));
    
    elementsList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@text='7/5/23']"));
```